# duplicated blocks are not detected from Sonar Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

We are currently using SonarQube server (version 5.1.1) 
and the Sonar Eclipse Plugin (version 3.5).
We are going to plan to upgrade SonarQube server to 5.2 and use SonarLint.

Regarding the rule "Source files should not have any duplicated blocks" (common-java:DuplicatedBlocks), we have seen a difference of behaviour 
between analysis results from SonarQube server and Sonar Eclipse Plugin.
Indeed duplicate blocks are not detected from the Sonar Eclipse Plugin while there are from SonarQube server.

Does SonarLint contain a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube for Eclipse and SonarLint for Eclipse do not provide feedback on Duplications or Code coverage.

Comment: Indeed - duplications are computed by the SonarQube server (as only the server is aware of the other projects). As SonarLint works independently of the SonarQube server, it cannot provide that rule.

Comment: Thanks. As the Sonar Eclipse plugin uses the SonarQube Server rules and the rule "common-java:DuplicatedBlocks" is very specific to detect duplication blocks in the same file (not about other projects), I'm surprised that nothing is detected from Sonar Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Analysis in Eclipse is in incremental mode, meaning that it only analyzes the differences. Thus, it cannot detect duplications.